# Loop through enum and check value of specific property

Tags: javascript

So I have an enum:

```
var enum = {
    aitem: {
        Desc: 'A description',
        Value: 0,
        Group: 'A'
    },
    bitem: {
        Desc: 'b description',
        Value: 1,
        Group: 'B'
    },
    bitem: {
        Desc: 'c description',
        Value: 2,
        Group: 'C'
    }
}
var neededGroup = 'A';
var neededValues = [];

//x.Group & x.Value don't exist
for (var x in enum){
    if (x.Group == neededGroup){
        neededValues.push(x.Value);
    }
}
```

So, basically I want to loop through my enum and check if the Group equals a specific group and if it does,I want to push that value onto an array. However, `x` appears to only be a string representing for example `aitem` and not a specific enum object.  How do I accomplish what I am trying to do since my current method won't work?

Comment: First, your enum is not defined correctly. It's missing comma `,`

Comment: `enum` is reserved anyway

Answer (score 2):

If you're only concerned with modern browsers then you can use for...of instead:

```
for (var x of yourEnum){
    if (x.Group == neededGroup){
        neededValues.push(x.Value);
    }
}
```

If you're also concerned with older browsers then you need to extract the object from the enum manually:

```
for (var key in yourEnum){
    var x = yourEnum[key];
    if (x.Group == neededGroup){
        neededValues.push(x.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should break out of the loop once a value is matched?

Answer (score 0):

`enum` is a reserved keyword so you should not use such reserved keywords.

Find a working example of your code below:

```
var t_enum = {
    aitem: {
        Desc: 'A description',
        Value: 0,
        Group: 'A'
    },
    bitem: {
        Desc: 'b description',
        Value: 1,
        Group: 'B'
    },
    bitem: {
        Desc: 'c description',
        Value: 2,
        Group: 'C'
    }
}
var neededGroup = 'A';
var neededValues = [];

Object.keys(t_enum).forEach(function (x) {
    var item = t_enum[x];
    if (item.Group == neededGroup){
        neededValues.push(item.Value);
        return;
    }
})
console.log(neededValues);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hc780x8m/)

Its an alternate approach from what Toddo is suggesting.